# Free multiplicative convolution of two random matrices

Tags: random-matrices, free-probability

Given two freely independent random hermitian matrices $A$ and $B$ following laws $\mu, \nu$, one can compute the empirical spectral distribution of $AB$ by their free multiplicative convolution $\mu\boxtimes\nu$ using the $S$-transform. Is there a way to compute the empirical spectral distribution of other products of $A$ and $B$, such as $AB^{-1}$?

(I am new to random matrix theory so the question might sound naive.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the possibility of dealing with any non-commutative rational function in A and B, by using more general (operator-valued) versions of free probability. Usually the corresponding equations cannot be solved analytically, but they are nice fixed-point equations which can be addressed numerically. See for example, chapter 10 in the book
[Mingo, Speicher: Free Probability and Random Matrices](https://rolandspeicher.com/literature/mingo-speicher/)
or the article
[Helton, Mai, Speicher: Applications of Realizations (aka Linearizations) to Free Probability](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.05330.pdf)

Comment: Thank you Prof Speicher for the references! For the relatively simple case of $AB^{-1}$, does the standard method work (see discussions above)?

Comment: @Shadumu In the case $AB^{-1}$ the standard method with the S-transform works; actually the S-transform S' of $B^{-1}$ can be expressed in terms of the S-transform S of B via $S'(z)=1/S(-1-z)$; this is shown in Prop. 3.13. of the paper:  U. Haagerup, H. Schultz, Brown measures of unbounded operators affiliated with a finite von Neumann algebra. Math. Scand. 100(2)

Comment: @RolandSpeicher Thanks a lot for the reference!

Answer (score 0):

If we denote the spectral density of $B$ by $\rho_{B} (\lambda )$, with $\lambda $ labeling the spectral values, then $\rho_{B^{-1} } (\lambda ) = (1/\lambda^{2} ) \rho_{B} (1/\lambda )$; also $B^{-1} $ and $A$ are freely independent, and you can convolve them multiplicatively using the $S$-transform.

Comment: Thanks! I can think of doing the S-tranform by first finding the resolvent/green function $G_B(z)=(1+w)/z$ from the density $\rho_B$ and then use $zwS(w)=1+w$ to solve for $S(w)$. Is the resolvent $G_{B^{-1}}(z)$ still convergent for $\rho_{B^{-1}}$? How is $G_{B^{-1}}(z)$ related to $G_B(z)$?

Comment: In general, there are no guarantees for the convergence of $G_{B^{-1} } (z)$ - if $B$ has eigenvalues near zero, then $B^{-1} $ will be correspondingly singular. And vice versa. I don't think there's a simple algebraic relation between $G_{B^{-1} } (z)$ and $G_{B} (z)$, but you can think of substituting $\lambda \rightarrow 1/\lambda $ in $G_{B^{-1} } (z)$ - then you're integrating over the same density as in $G_{B} (z)$, but with a changed kernel ...

Comment: Thanks. Are you aware of any references that properly treat such a case?

Comment: Not sure whether I properly treated these things, but I played with them in hep-th/9604012 and hep-th/9609216. Note that I edited my answer - I was originally missing the $(1/\lambda^{2} )$ measure factor in $\rho_{B^{-1} } $.